# Array of JLabel reference

Tags: java

I have a problem referencing to the JLabel in the array.
I've created the array of existing JLabels:

```
 JLabel[] RejestryDlugie = {lA, lB, lC, lD};
```

And when I try to get any information about it (f.e. through the actionlistener)

```
System.out.println(RejestryDlugie[0].getText());
```

I get an error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Is `lA` null, has it be assigned?

Comment: it is not. It is i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the JLabels before referencing them, as that is probably why you are getting a NullPointerException.